# Where do I find ALL the running processes (apps, background, etc)?

Tags: task-management, processes

My phone gets pretty slow as I install new apps and when I try to see what is running in order to kill those processes, I kill everything anoying but the phone keeps slow.

Is there an app or screen on Android which tells me EVERYTHING that is running on the phone?

Comment: Are you rooted?  Running `ps aux` as root is one way.

Comment: No. I'm not. Actually I need a user-like solution. No rooting or other "pyrotechnics".